# can't compare password and confirm password strings and show a error message

Tags: javascript, react-native

hi I am new to react components, i cant pass a function with 2 values and compare the 2 password strings and show the error message. I could only get the error message from the first password text and no result from the 2nd confirm password error message.
i am hoping to get help in this.

thanks in advance!

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View,Text ,StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Keyboard, TouchableWithoutFeedback} from "react-native";
import { ScrollView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";





const SignUpPage= ({navigation}) => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [emailValidError, setEmailValidError] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("")
    const [passwordErrorMessaage, setPasswordErrorMessage] = useState("")
    const [passwordConfirm, setConfirmPassword] = useState("")
    const [confirmPasswordErrorMessaage, setConfirmPasswordErrorMessage] = useState("")
   
    
    const handlePasswordError =(password,passwordConfirm) => {
        
        if (password.length === 0) {
          setPasswordErrorMessage('enter the password');
        } else if (password.length > 8 || password.length<20) {
          setPasswordErrorMessage('Min character 8 & maximum 20');
        } else if (password.length < 8 || password.length>20) {
            setPasswordErrorMessage('');
        }else if (password !== passwordConfirm) {
          setConfirmPasswordErrorMessage('The entered passwords doesnt match');
        } else if (passwordConfirm.length ==0){
         setConfirmPasswordErrorMessage('Fill all required fields');
        } else if (password === passwordConfirm) {
            setConfirmPasswordErrorMessage("")
        } 

        
        };
        


    const handleValidEmail = val => {
        let reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w\w+)+$/;
        if (val.length === 0) {
          setEmailValidError('email address must be enter');
        } else if (reg.test(val) === false) {
          setEmailValidError('enter valid email address');
        } else if (reg.test(val) === true) {
          setEmailValidError('');
        }
        };
        

    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss} accessible={false}>
        <ScrollView style={styles.cont}>
            <View style={styles.container}> 
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>Sign Up to my app</Text>
            <TextInput  style={styles.input}
            title='Email'
            placeholder="E-mail"
            onChangeText={value => {
            setEmail(value);
            handleValidEmail(value);
            }}>   
            </TextInput>
            {emailValidError ? <Text>{emailValidError}</Text> : null}
            <TextInput style={styles.input}
            title='Password' 
            placeholder="password"
            secureTextEntry
            onChangeText={value1 => {
            setPassword(value1);
            handlePasswordError(password,passwordConfirm);
            }} >
            </TextInput>
            {passwordErrorMessaage ? <Text>{passwordErrorMessaage}</Text> : null}
            <TextInput style={styles.input}
            title='Confirm Password'
            placeholder=" Confirm password"
            secureTextEntry
            onChangeText={value2 => {
                setConfirmPassword(value2);
                handlePasswordError(password,passwordConfirm);
                }} > 
            </TextInput>
            {confirmPasswordErrorMessaage ? <Text>{confirmPasswordErrorMessaage}</Text> : null}
            <TextInput style={styles.input}  title='Educational Qualification' placeholder="Educational Qualification" ></TextInput>
            <TextInput style={styles.input}  title='Current Postion' placeholder="Current Postion" ></TextInput>
            <View style={styles.btncont}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.Usrbtn} onPress={()=> alert('Sign Up Successfull')} > 
                    <Text style={styles.Usrtxt}> Sign Up</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.Usrbtn} onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('Login')}>
                    <Text style={styles.Usrtxt}> Login Page</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            </View>
            </ScrollView>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )
}
 


const styles =StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex:1,
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center',
        backgroundColor: '#A83EE1',
    },
    welcome:{
        fontSize:30,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 15,
        color:'#fff',
        fontFamily: 'DancingScript-Bold'
    },
    input:{
        width:'90%',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        padding: 15,
        marginBottom: 10,
    },
    Usrbtn:{
        backgroundColor: "#FFD7FF",
        padding:15,
        width:"45%"
    },
    Usrtxt:{
        fontSize:18,
        textAlign:'center'
    },
    btncont:{
        flexDirection:'row',
        justifyContent:'space-between',
        width:"90%"
    },
    textDanger: {
        color: "#dc3545"
    },
    cont:{
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor: '#A83EE1'
    }
});

export default SignUpPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the state is being set the component will rerender so once you have one of the if's satisfied its not getting to last else if.

So once the password.length is being satisfied the state is being set and the else if doesn't come into play.

Maybe try a condition if the passwordconfirm is "" then review the password - if its not then continue on to the next part.

```
   const handlePasswordError =(password,passwordConfirm) => {
        
if(passwordConfirm === ""){

        if (password.length === 0) {
          setPasswordErrorMessage('enter the password');
        } else if (password.length > 8 || password.length<20) {
          setPasswordErrorMessage('Min character 8 & maximum 20');
        } else if (password.length < 8 || password.length>20) {
            setPasswordErrorMessage('');
        }
} else {
if (password !== passwordConfirm) {
          setConfirmPasswordErrorMessage('The entered passwords doesnt match');
        } else if (passwordConfirm.length ==0){
         setConfirmPasswordErrorMessage('Fill all required fields');
        } else if (password === passwordConfirm) {
            setConfirmPasswordErrorMessage("")
        } 
}
```

or something like that so the if statement considers the passwordconfirm before it stops at the password length